# this._subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, ngrx

I try to subscribe my Observable "TemplateName" and I have this error,

I don't know what :

```
templateName: Observable<string>;
this.templateName = this.requestDetail.request.templateName;
```

It sends me this back to the console :

> Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: Array(1)}
>   _isScalar
>   :
>   false
>   _subscribe
>   :
>   ["deploy"]
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object

I try to subscribe :

```
this.subscriptions.push(this.templateName.subscribe.bind(this.templateName)(templateName => {
                this.store.dispatch(new requestActions.LoadTemplateAction(templateName))
            }))
```

And I have this error :

> this._subscribe is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.requestDetail.request.templateName` must be an Observable for you to subscribe.

`this.templateName` is declared as an Observable so `.request.templateName` must be of the same type. Maybe this help you:

```
templateName = new Subject<string>();
request.templateName: Observable<string> = this.templateName.asObservable();
```

here the varaible .`request.template` is your `this.requestDetail.request.templateName`
so  when you call `this.requestDetail.request.templateName` it should return an `Observable`. Then in your service or place where you declared templateName if you do `templateName.next('some string')` when you subscribe to `this.requestDetail.request.templateName` or `this.tamplatename` after `this.tamplatename = this.requestDetail.request.templateName` your data must be 'some string'

Other way without Subject is this:

```
request.templateName: Observable<string> = new Observable((observer) => {
    // observable execution
    observer.next("bla bla bla")
    observer.complete()
})
```

Check [this](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3) and [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html) for more information.